I want to mock Constructor of a class and still call real methods of that class using Mockito
I am trying to unit test a class A, where I call a method in its Constructor getB(). I want to Unit test this class A without calling this method inside the constructor in order to test other methods inside the class.
class A {
  B b;

  public A() {
    B = getB();
  }

  doSomething() {
    b.doOtherThing();
  }

  getB() {
    return somethingThatReturnB;
  }
}

@Test
class TestA {
  @Spy
  A a;

  @Mock
  B b;

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
    MockiyoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    doReturn(smt).when(b).doOtherThing();
    a.doSomething();
  }
}

I tried the mocking constructor but this doesn't call the real Method I want to test.

That's terible design, have A depend on somethingThatReturnB and provide the dependency through the constructor. That aside, mockito has doCallRealMethod(), thenCallRealMethod() for that.

@Chaosfire I tried to do this, but I get an NPE, because of null value in the mocked Class B inside Class A, it is like A doesn't recognize the mocked b. (inside the Test Class b is not null but in class A when testing doSomething(). It is null.

Mockito has a when(systemUnderTest.methodToTest()).thenCallRealMethod(); option which allows you to explicitly call the real method. You'd have to do it for each method in the class though.
Because you are mocking the constructor, though, the value of B b in your example never gets set to anything. One way around this would be to use the ReflectionTestUtils class from org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils to explicitly set the value of the object (instead of, or as well as, mocking the constructor call):
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(systemUnderTest, "b", // mock object and field name
        mockB); // the object to put in place of B

